# How to activate or select pivot fields in pivot table

Tags: excel, select, pivot-table, vba

I am new to VBA and I am trying to activate my pivot table, and select fields from the pivot table.

How do I write it in VBA code?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want count or sum value, you should use this code

`Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(1);
debug.print pt.GetPivotData("data field", "field1", "item1"......)`
This is almost same like ordinary GetPivotData function.

If you want text wallue of column, you could use this

`Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(1);
For Each pt1 In pt.RowFields("Name of column").PivotItems;
debug.print pt1.value;
next`